# Xamarin.Android: Unable to get device Mac Address in Android-11

Tags: xamarin.android, mac-address, android-10.0, android-9.0-pie, android-11

I  have developed an appliation which get the device mac address and then query from the database. Previously my app was working fine but now I am migrating to Android-11 and not able to get Mac address. I don't have real device for testing/debugging but my client reported that he is not having mac address. Can any body please guide why I am having working app not working for latest android versions or if there is any critical update.

Comment: Android 11 introduces changes related to MAC addresses. These changes affect apps only if they target Android 11. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/mac-address There is no more updates for Android 11. It would be better to use other versions.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT my clients are using latest devices so how can I use other versions. Its their requirement. The link you provided, I already visited and found no any useful point. I am really amazed that almost developers are in all over the world and no one has faced this issue or no one has solution for this issue.

Comment: You could use the other versions of Android instead of Android 11. For now, Android 11 do not have any updates for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, Working with MAC for unique device identification is not best practice. Instead using MAC address we should use Android ID.
https://www.appsflyer.com/mobile-attribution-glossary/device-id/

var deviceId = Plugin.DeviceInfo.CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id;

Plugin.DeviceInfo.CrossDeviceInfo - i have used "DeviceInfoPlugin"

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin